Why isn't the latest Firefox supported by Discord?
When I try enabling microphone, Discord prompts me to use “latest Chrome, Firefox, Opera, or Edge”, even if I’m already visiting the site with the latest Firefox. Discord isn’t requesting the permission at all, so this KB article doesn’t help.

According to this question, the root cause is the “Disable WebRTC” Firefox extension. There is no per-website configuration (due to Firefox limitation), so I would have to temporarily disable that extension before using Discord. Of course, alternatively one can simply use another browser for Discord.

I could be mistaken, but I think in Mozilla's implementation of MV3, it may now be possible to support per-website configurations.  Of course, the extension would need to be coded to do so.

@EndAntisemiticHate Would you mind sharing a bit more details? I checked the API they use; it doesn’t seem to support specifying something like an allow-list (a list of websites that I want to grant WebRTC access, such as Discord).

Hi Franklin. Are you asking from an extension developer's point of view or from an end-user's point of view?
